# How to access property of @Embeddable class by QueryDSL

Tags: java, querydsl

My entity class has composite key as a different class with `@EmbeddedId`
how can i use querydsl to retrieve property of Embdebbable class property

I have tried creating JPQL query but it is not able to identify the property under `@Embeddable` class

```
@Entity
class A{
  @EmbeddedId
  B b
}

@Embeddable
class B{
  @Column(name = "id")
  private String Id;
  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;
}
```

when i am trying

```
BooleanExpression exp1=QA.QB.Id.eq(QC.QD.buid);
JPQLQuery query = from(QA).where(exp1);
QueryResults<Object> results=query.fetchResults();
```

> Here i am getting error saying cant found path A.B.id
>
> Invalid path: 'A.B.id' unexpected end of subtree